# I just switched to Next v13 and I'm trying to implement redux, but I keep getting this context error. what am I doing wrong? what should I do?

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

I want to create a game and keep count of the user's life in the redux store. so i created a life slice like this:

```
export const lifeslice = createSlice({
  name: "life",
  initialState: {
    life: 5,
  },

  reducers: {
    increment: (state) => {
      state.life += 1;
    },

    decrement: (state) => {
      state.life -= 1;
    },
  },
});

export const { increment, decrement } = lifeslice.actions;


export default lifeslice.reducer;
```

and in my /app/layout.js  this is how I set up the provider

```
import "./global.css";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "../redux/store";
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html>
      <head />

      <body>
        <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

and here is the error [image]

Comment: Hi, you need to just add "use client"; at top of your layout and pages.

Comment: Oh man, thank you! I've fixed it. I'm getting a different error now, but I can see redux functioning in the console. I'll do the rest. <3

Answer (score 1):

Adding the "use client" at the top of your code works

```
"use client"
import "./global.css";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "../redux/store";
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html>
      <head />

      <body>
        <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```